# Do while loop to delete characters until count is achieved not working Java

Tags: java, string, replace, do-while

I'm trying to make this do while loop delete vowels from a string until the correct character count is reached (140), however it is not working. I'm unsure if the do while loop is working then stopping once the condition is met but if that is the case how can I run the rest of my code once the condition is met?
Thanks in advance!
Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase to be shortened: ");
    String toCompress = scan.nextLine();
    int length = toCompress.length();
    System.out.println(length);;

    do {
        toCompress = toCompress.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "");
    }while(length >= 140);


    System.out.println("Compressed phrase: ");
    System.out.println(toCompress);
    int length2 = toCompress.length();
    System.out.print(length2);; 
    scan.close();

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. What results are you getting when running your program?

Comment: Define ["however it is not working"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: BTW: `string.replaceAll(target, replacement)` replaces all of occurrences of `target` with `replacement`, so doing it in loop doesn't really make much sense for `replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "")` since it will replace all of vowels at once.

Comment: Does `nextLine()` wait for the user to type anything? I don't think so, because then simply calling `nextLine()` to skip past the newline character wouldn't work. You probably have to use `next()` instead.

Comment: It runs up to the first System.out.println(length) then nothing shows up after that. The whole reason that I'm trying to use the loop is because I want the program to stop deleting the vowels once 140 characters is reached then print the new phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a better way to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random RNG = new Random(); //Set up the RNG
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in ); //Set up the scanner
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase to be shortened: ");
    String toCompress = scan.nextLine();
    //Setup the string builder with the user input
    StringBuilder shorten = new StringBuilder(toCompress); 

    //Wile the length is greater than or equal to 140,do some conversions then 
    //run the if statement
    while (shorten.length() >= 140)
    {
        int randChar = RNG.nextInt(shorten.length());
        char convertToChar = shorten.charAt(randChar);
        int convertToInt = (int)convertToChar;

        //If statement choosing which ASCII chars to delete (vowels)
            if ((convertToInt > 32) || (convertToInt == 65)
                    || (convertToInt == 69) || (convertToInt == 73)
                    || (convertToInt == 79) || (convertToInt == 85))
                        {
                            shorten.deleteCharAt(randChar);
                        }
    }
    System.out.println("Compressed phrase:");
    System.out.println(shorten);
    System.out.println(shorten.length());

    scan.close();   
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove one vowel at a time until it reaches the 140 length. Right now you don't update the length after doing toCompress = toCompress.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "")
Correct way:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    String[] vow={"A","a","O","o","E","e","U","u","I","i"};
    List<String> vowels=Arrays.asList(vow);
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase to be shortened: ");
    String toCompress = scan.nextLine();
    int length = toCompress.length();
    System.out.println(length);

    String compressed="";

    while(length >= 140&&compressed.length()<140){
        String firstLetter=toCompress.substring(0,1);
        //if the first letter is not a vowel, add it to the compressed string
        if(!vowels.contains(firstLetter)) compressed.concat(firstLetter);   
        //remove the first letter from toCompress
        toCompress=toCompress.substring(1);
        //update the length to the new value
        length=compressed.length()+toCompress.length();     
    }
    //After reaching 140 characters, concatenate the rest of toCompress to compressed
    compressed.concat(toCompress);

    System.out.println("Compressed phrase: ");
    System.out.println(compressed);
    System.out.print(compressed.length()); 
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: For me, this compiles without error but deletes the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using the while loop here. replaceAll() will look for all the characters in your string that match the regex/pattern you've provided, and replace them with the character/pattern in your second argument (which in this case is an empty string). Doing it in a loop will not change the result, and is useless in this case.

The while loop will also never complete in cases where there are more than a 140 non-vowel characters in the string. Look up the documentation for replaceAll() and understand how it works. Useful link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm

Comment: The whole reason that I'm trying to use the loop is because I want the program to stop deleting the vowels once 140 characters is reached then print the new phrase.